# Ignoring schema name on sql select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, schema, replication

using SQL server 2014 I am able to select without specifying the schema name when it is NOT DBO.

We are now switching over to SQL 2016 and I am no longer able to select without adding the schema name?

Problem: Going back into each stored proc to add the schema name in would take a lot of time so I was wondering if it is possible to ignore the schema name somehow? I have been searching google but haven't found anything..

The procs are used in our SSRS reports, which there are over 100 and some are embedded into the reports so if there is a way to avoid having to change each one that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the default schema is a property of the connecting user. Maybe you should check how the new "migrated" user has been defined.

Comment: The user that the reports use is setup the same on both servers as well as my user login.